# How to parse dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm using API "chess.com" and I try to learn better dict:

```
{'url': 'https://www.chess.com/live/game/8554438187', 'pgn': '[Event "Live Chess"]\n[Site "Chess.com"]\n[Date "2021.03.03"]\n[Round "-"]\n[White "AHMEDAHMED1984"]\n[Black "pgmendormi"]\n[Result "0-1"]
```

i need url so i did:

```
data = get_player_game_archives(username).json

url = data['archives'][-1]
games = requests.get(url).json()

game = games['games'][-1]
print(games['games'][-1]['url'])
```

but how can I get `"[Result "0-1"]"`
I tried:

```
print(games['games'][-1]['url'][1])
```

but it gives me only one character, do I have to do a loop?

And how?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: The `.json()` in `data = ...` seems to suggest that you're getting json data. Maybe `json.loads(...)` will be useful in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`games['games'][-1]['pgn'].splitlines()[-1]` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the tips :)